# Como acessar o DrawerMenu no flutter de várias telas?

Tags: navigation-drawer, flutter

Estou Começando um aplicação em `Flutter`, adicionei na minha `HomePage` um `DrawerMenu`, Funciona bem, porém quando acesso outra página, queria que o menu pudesse ser aberto de qualquer uma.
Vi alguns exemplos criando o `Drawer` em arquivos separados, mas não consegui por em meu projeto.

Meu Drawer:

```
        drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(

            child:  Image.asset("assets/quadro.jpg"),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white24,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Home'),
              onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => HomePage(),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Item 2'),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um arquivo novo chamado "CustomDrawer" e insira nele um novo Widget (pode ser o StateLess mesmo). Coloque no "return" desse widget o código do seu Drawer.

```
Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(

        child:  Image.asset("assets/quadro.jpg"),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white24,
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
          onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Item 2'),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Após fazer isso tudo que precisará fazer é chamar esse CustomDrawer em cada componente AppBar que inserir nas telas da sua aplicação.

É necessário porém tomar cuidado e pensar direitinho no comportamento do empilhamento das telas. Aconselho realizar diversos testes acionando elas e utilizando o BackButtom do aparelho para verificar se a pilha está na ordem que deseja. Em alguns casos precisará fazer a substituição dela ao invés de apenas o empilhamento normal.

Comment: Ótimo Leonardo, funcionou muito bem isso, a parte de empilhamento irei repensar mais além, por enquanto tendo o menu acessado de qualquer tela já me ajuda muito. Obrigado.